# How can I replace the first value in the second list with the last value in the previous list?

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, loops, object

In this list of objects we have value `groupID`, Which contains a list.

What I want is to replace the first value in the list with the last value in the previous list.

```
let testArr = [
    {groupID: [1900, 1890, 1880], Letter: "A"},
    {groupID:[1888, 1898, 1908, 1918, 1928, 1938], Letter: "B"},
    {groupID: [1927, 1917, 1907], Letter: "A"},
    {groupID: [1912, 1922, 1932, 1942, 2012, 2022, 2032, 2042], Letter: "B"},
    {groupID: [2039, 2029, 2019, 2009], Letter: "A"},
    {groupID: [2013, 2023, 2033], Letter: "B"},
]
```

The result is:

```
let testArr = [
    {groupID: [1900, 1890, 1880], Letter: "A"},
    {groupID:[1880, 1898, 1908, 1918, 1928, 1938], Letter: "B"},
    {groupID: [1938, 1917, 1907], Letter: "A"},
    {groupID: [1907, 1922, 1932, 1942, 2012, 2022, 2032, 2042], Letter: "B"},
    {groupID: [2042, 2029, 2019, 2009], Letter: "A"},
    {groupID: [2009, 2023, 2033], Letter: "B"},
]
```

I have this code, but it's silly and doesn't work with `async and await`:

```
let add = []

for (let i = 0; i < testArr.length; i++){
    if (testArr[i].groupID.length != 0){
        add.push(testArr[i].groupID[testArr[i].groupID.length-1])
    }
}
for (let i = 1; i < testArr.length; i++){

    testArr[i].groupID.splice(0,1, add[i-1])
}
```

and Thanks in advance.

Comment: for all i > 0 change the `testArr[i].groupID[0] = testArr[i-1].groupID[testArr[i-1].groupID.length - 1]` so start loop with i=1

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work with `async` and `await`"?

Comment: But do so in _descending_ order of `i`, because there may be `groupID`s of length 1.

Comment: @BenDavidsson ... your originally posted code and question does focus on the solution of the specific replacement algorithm. Though it does mention problems with handling asynchronous requests/code, the latter should have been addressed separately, supported by problem specific, boiled down, example code as well. Question which do focus on more than one specific problem, even more if not correctly specified/explained, tend to get closed in a short period of time. Therefore, please edit your question accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand why your code needs to work with `async`/ `await` but a possible solution to your problem could look as follows:

```js
const testArr = [
    {groupID: [1900, 1890, 1880], Letter: "A"},
    {groupID: [1888, 1898, 1908, 1918, 1928, 1938], Letter: "B"},
    {groupID: [1927, 1917, 1907], Letter: "A"},
    {groupID: [1912, 1922, 1932, 1942, 2012, 2022, 2032, 2042], Letter: "B"},
    {groupID: [2039, 2029, 2019, 2009], Letter: "A"},
    {groupID: [2013, 2023, 2033], Letter: "B"}
];

let lastValue;
const result = testArr.map((o) => {
  const tmpLastValue = o.groupID[o.groupID.length - 1];
  if (lastValue) {
     o.groupID = [lastValue, ...o.groupID.splice(1)];
  }
  lastValue = tmpLastValue;
  return o;
});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: The code works well, thank you very much for the help, but when I use async it does not work and I do not know why.

const main = async()=>{
    let data = await d3.csv('./file.csv');
    // code Here
}
main()

Comment: @BenDavidsson ... your originally posted code and question does focus on the solution of the specific replacement algorithm. Though it does mention problems with handling asynchronous requests/code, the latter should have been addressed separately, supported by problem specific, boiled down, example code as well. Question which do focus on more than one specific problem, even more if not correctly specified/explained, tend to get closed in a short period of time. Therefore, please edit your question accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if you're trying to replace the elements in the same array of objects or need to return a new array. However, here is a solution to replace the elements in the same array.

Update: Based on your comment, it seems you need this transformation to happen from the end to the beginning of the list. I have commented my previous code and kept it for reference, though.

```js
let testArr = [
    {groupID: [1900, 1890, 1880], Letter: "A"},
    {groupID:[1888, 1898, 1908, 1918, 1928, 1938], Letter: "B"},
    {groupID: [1927, 1917, 1907], Letter: "A"},
    {groupID: [1912, 1922, 1932, 1942, 2012, 2022, 2032, 2042], Letter: "B"},
    {groupID: [2039, 2029, 2019, 2009], Letter: "A"},
    {groupID: [2013, 2023, 2033], Letter: "B"},
]

// testArr.forEach((item, index) => {
//     index && (item.groupID[0] = testArr[index-1].groupID[testArr[index-1].groupID.length-1]);
// })

for (let i = testArr.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
    testArr[i].groupID[0] = testArr[i-1].groupID[testArr[i-1].groupID.length-1];
}

console.log(testArr);
```

Please note that there could be multiple solutions to this depending upon what exactly you need to achieve. Also, you need to explain what do you mean by running this code with `async` and `await`?

Comment: I tried with length 1, as well, and it works. Can you please elaborate your scenario?

Comment: If I understood your use case correctly, I have updated the answer, and if this is what you need to achieve?

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help, I use D3.js and that's why I use async and await. I don't know why these solutions don't work.

Answer (score 1):

The OP's specification can be implemented almost literally ...

```js
testArr
  // ... for each array item ...
  .forEach((item, idx, arr) => {

    // ... which is not the first item ...
    if (idx >= 1) {

      // ... replace the current item's first `groupID` array item ...
      item.groupID[0] =
        // ... with the previous items's last `groupID` array item.
        arr[idx - 1].groupID.at(-1);
    }
  });

console.log({ testArr });
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script>
  const testArr = [
    { groupID: [1900, 1890, 1880], Letter: "A" },
    { groupID: [1888, 1898, 1908, 1918, 1928, 1938], Letter: "B"} ,
    { groupID: [1927, 1917, 1907], Letter: "A" },
    { groupID: [1912, 1922, 1932, 1942, 2012, 2022, 2032, 2042], Letter: "B" },
    { groupID: [2039, 2029, 2019, 2009], Letter: "A" },
    { groupID: [2013, 2023, 2033], Letter: "B" },
  ];
</script>
```

**Edit**

In case one also wants to cover already mentioned edge cases where either the current item's or the previous item's or both items' `groupId` array(s) do(es) feature just a single item, the above shown example code could slightly change to the following code ...

```js
testArr
  // ... for each array item ...
  .forEach((item, idx, arr) => {
    if (
      // ... which is not the first item ... 
      idx >= 1 &&
      // ... and only in case its groupID` array has more than just 1 item ...
      item.groupID.length > 1 &&
      // ... and the previous items's groupID` array has more than just 1 item too ...
      arr[idx - 1].groupID.length > 1
    ) {
      // ... replace the current item's first `groupID` array item ...
      item.groupID[0] =
        // ... with the previous items's last `groupID` array item.
        arr[idx - 1].groupID.at(-1);
    }
  });

console.log({ testArr });
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script>
  const testArr = [
    { groupID: [1900], Letter: "A" },
    { groupID: [1888], Letter: "B"} ,
    { groupID: [1927, 1917, 1907], Letter: "A" },
    { groupID: [1912, 1922, 1932, 1942, 2012, 2022, 2032, 2042], Letter: "B" },
    { groupID: [2039], Letter: "A" },
    { groupID: [2013, 2023, 2033], Letter: "B" },
  ];
</script>
```

Comment: This does not work if there are `groupID`s of length 1.

Comment: Of cause it does work ... the question is whether the OP's specification does accept the result of how such a scenario gets handled or whether such a case should be covered by a yet to be specified extra handling.

Comment: I interpret the OP's specification differently. Let's see.

Answer (score 1):

```js
let testArr = [
    {groupID: [1900, 1890, 1880], Letter: "A"},
    {groupID:[1888, 1898, 1908, 1918, 1928, 1938], Letter: "B"},
    {groupID: [1927, 1917, 1907], Letter: "A"},
    {groupID: [1912, 1922, 1932, 1942, 2012, 2022, 2032, 2042], Letter: "B"},
    {groupID: [2039, 2029, 2019, 2009], Letter: "A"},
    {groupID: [2013, 2023, 2033], Letter: "B"},
];

for (let i = 1; i < testArr.length; i++) {
    const previousGroupID = testArr[i - 1].groupID;
    const lastValueOfPreviousGroup = previousGroupID[previousGroupID.length - 1];
    
    // Update the first value of the current groupID with the last value of the previous group
    testArr[i].groupID[0] = lastValueOfPreviousGroup;
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(testArr));
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a version which does this in an immutable manner:

```js
const cycleGroups = (xs) => xs.map(
  ({groupID, ...rest}, i, a) => ({
    groupID: i > 0 && a[i - 1].groupID.length > 0 
        ? [a[i - 1].groupID.at(-1), ...groupID.slice(1)] 
        : [...groupID], 
    ...rest
  })
)

const testArr = [{groupID: [1900, 1890, 1880], Letter: "A"}, {groupID:[1888, 1898, 1908, 1918, 1928, 1938], Letter: "B"}, {groupID: [1927, 1917, 1907], Letter: "A"}, {groupID: [1912, 1922, 1932, 1942, 2012, 2022, 2032, 2042], Letter: "B"}, {groupID: [2039, 2029, 2019, 2009], Letter: "A"}, {groupID: [2013, 2023, 2033], Letter: "B"}]

console.log(cycleGroups(testArr))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

This handles length `0` and length `1` `groupID` arrays, although it has to make some assumptions about what's wanted in those cases.

We simply `map` over our entries, and create a new `groupID` id based on the prior one (if our index is positive) and upon whether the prior one actually has elements in its `groupID`.   The remaining fields are carried over by reference.  Note the subtlety of shallow cloning the `groupID` array for the first record.  In all other records, the output `groupID` is a new array.  We don't want to leave the first one as a reference to its input.

Again, note that this is an immutable operation.  No arrays are harmed in the running of this code.  We do have a modicum of civilization here, after all!